# Cake 2 data model for complex habtm relationship - saving and loading

Tags: cakephp, join, save, has-and-belongs-to-many

Abstract extra simplified example of issue:

DB structure is (simple version):

```
orders {
 id,
 name
}

items {
 id,
 name
}

items_orders {
 order_id,
 item_id,
 quantity # problem item - many to many tables don't usually have this can't get cake to upport
}
```

So I have controllers and models for orders and items, they both habtm each other via the joinTable items_orders with the foreign keys specified, and I can load an order and all it's items, or an item and all the orders it is in, and save them, etc, however I can't figure out how to save/recover the quantity.

I am assuming I'll need to create an extra model to handle this, but can't find any documentation or similar posts here that explain how, or if there's an easy shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using extra fields in join table is easy and explained in the cookbook.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

Comment: No Idea how I missed this, thanks. Can't upvote your answer due to being too new :(

Comment: If I may also ask here:
I used to save as:
    $this->Order->save( array( 'Order' => array( 'field' => 'value' ), 'Item' => array( 'Item' => array( id1, id2, idx ) ) );
Doing this now throws me an error:
    Model "Order" is not associated with model "Item"
But now stuck on how the third joining model is added how to save the whole thing... (as well as how to include the extra quantity field) - Is there a similar cookbook page I can't find on saving this type of structure?

Comment: Do you have your model association as described in the cookbook? Order hasmany ItemOrder, Item hasmany ItemOrder and ItemOrder belongsto Order and Item? I would do the following: adding a few data to the database manually and try a find, than you will see how to do it.